# Finding dissimilar dimensions in a feature vector in Mahout

Tags: machine-learning, mahout, pearson

If I use a similarity based algorithm such as pearson correlation score to compare two feature vectors
and I want to know those dimensions/feature fields which are very much dissimilar amongst the feature set then what is the algorithm to be used? I am using Mahout which is a machine learning library for Java

Comment: This is not really a programming question, is it?

Comment: I am using Mahout which is a machine learning library in Java

Comment: If you want to get feedback here, you should mention that in your question and perhaps post the piece of code you are working on as well.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? Find similarities between data in 2 vectors?

Comment: @Adrian - I have explained in detail below to Sean Owen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it would just be the dimension in which the two vectors differed most -- in which the absolute value of the difference of the vectors' values in the dimension was largest. Is that really all you mean or are you looking for something subtler?

Comment: Ok say I have fv1, fv2, fv3, fv4 and fv5 as the feature vectors which are supposed to be very "similar". Now for feature vector 2 = fv2(say) I need to find which dimensions are awkward or have a large variation of disimilarity as compared to the other dimensions. For this I want to compare fv2 with all other feature vectors and then come up with the answer.So I need to calculate average absolute difference across all vectors or is there some better statistic?

Comment: Absolute difference from the average is reasonable; I might suggest something more normalized like a z-value -- just the number of standard deviations from the mean the value is.